# Spring mvc with maven giving noHandlerFound error

Tags: java, spring, maven

I created a spring mvc maven application as described below using spring tool suite Version: 3.6.4.RELEASE

here is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mytcg</groupId>
  <artifactId>firstapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>firstapp Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>firstapp</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

here is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<servlet>
<servlet-name>firstappservlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>firstappservlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

here is the servlet-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mytcg.controller"/>


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name= "prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name= "suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

<!-- 
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp"> </bean>
 -->
</beans>
```

here is the HelloController.java

```
package com.mytcg.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value ="/greeting" )
    public String sayHell (Model model){

        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hellooo world");

        return "hello";
    }

}
```

here is the hello.jsp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>${greeting}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

After i run it, it shows "Hello World!"

But when i give the following url for greeting.html

```
http://localhost:8083/firstapp/greeting.html
```

it gives following error with 404

```
Apr 04, 2016 9:40:17 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/firstapp/greeting.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'firstappservlet'
```

Comment: please share  full stack trace of your exception

Comment: change `<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` just try

Comment: What is firstapp? is it the context-root of your web project? Also, what is greeting.html ?

Comment: firstapp is my application name and greeting is my url in controller to call

Comment: try this: http://localhost:8083/greeting.html

Comment: Make sure that your app is deployed at `/firstapp` and not at `/`. Try the same URL without `/firstapp` and see what works.

Comment: Enable debug logging for `org.springframework.web` or all from `org.springframework` and see if your `@Controller` is detected.

Comment: Also what do you mean with *after I run it, it shows "Hello World!"*? How are you deploying this, is it even a maven project?

Answer (score 0):

the your problem is in the your controller.

In your controller the @RequestMapping listen on the /greeting but you fire a http request form your borwser for http://localhost:8083/firstapp/greeting.html

you should change the your controller in this way:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value ="/greeting.html" )
    public String sayHell (Model model){

      ...
    }

}
```

However the my personal advice is taht you should not tie you to a scpecific implementation and you should use for @RequestMapping method as you did configure the dispatcherServlet in this way:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and use for your url a pattern like this: http://localhost:8083/firstapp/greeting

I hope that this can help you

Comment: Although it might look that `/greeting` doesn't work it actually adds, by default` a mapping for `/greeting.*` which wil match the `greeting.html`. If you enable debug logging for `org.springframework.web` you will see the detected mappings.

Comment: ok but if I change the mapping in the annotation for me it work

Comment: My comment might be a bit to short, it also depends on if you use `<mvc:annotation-driven />` (or `@EnableWebMvc`) or use the defaults from the dispatcher servlet and which Spring version you use.

Comment: I use always <mvc:annotation-driven /> it was enougth in any my case

Answer (score -1):

change your `web.xml` like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<servlet>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
 <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

change your xml file name like `servlet-config.xml`  to `dispatcher-servlet.xml` and configure `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`

Your `dispatcher-servlet.xml`is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
        <mvc:annotation-driven/>
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.mytcg.controller"/>


        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name= "prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name= "suffix" value=".jsp"/>
        </bean>
   <!--configuring HandlerMapping --> 
     <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
    </beans>
```

Comment: i tried adding <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/> but still same error

Comment: try to clean build your project and run again. if same exceptions is raising let me know

Comment: That won't help, nor will adding the old and deprecated `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` do anything (the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` already registers the newer and advices `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`.).